# Unexpected behavior on click at one UITextField on UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have one TabbedView with 4 Tabs inside.
At the first and second tab (first without scroll and second with it) when i click at one UITextField the ScrollView has a normal behavior. See the GIFs bellow:

[image]
[image]

But on my third view with scroll, when i click at one field on top of cell, the scroll rolls to bottom of cell, and when i click at a TextField on bottom of cell it rolls to top of cell:
[image]

So, i have no actions on any UIText (see the controller bellow):

```
class TratamentoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var procedimentoTitle: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var naoRotoSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var giganteSwitch: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var paralisiaCompleta: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var paralisiaIncompleta: UISwitch!
@IBOutlet weak var efeitoDeMassaSwitch: UISwitch!

@IBOutlet weak var duduGeral: UITextField!

var indexPath : NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath()
var parentTable : UITableViewController = UITableViewController()
@IBOutlet weak var alterarButton: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    procedimentoTitle.borderBottom(UIColor(red: 225/255, green: 225/255, blue: 225/255, alpha: 1).CGColor)

    naoRotoSwitch.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75)
    giganteSwitch.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75)
    efeitoDeMassaSwitch.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75)
    paralisiaCompleta.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75)
    paralisiaIncompleta.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75, 0.75)

    alterarButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    //let recgonizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(TratamentoTableViewCell.printa) )
    //procedimentoTitle.addGestureRecognizer(recgonizer)

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

I already tried

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 712
}
```

and i tried

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

TratamentoTableViewController (complete code)

```
import UIKit

class TratamentoViewController: UITableViewController {

var tratamento : [AneurismaTratamento] = [
    AneurismaTratamento(),
    AneurismaTratamento(),
    AneurismaTratamento()
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

//Code above added as commented (Works but not as i wish), sometimes the keyboard appear over the textfield
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tratamento.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    return self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TratamentoCell")! as! TratamentoTableViewCell

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the View Controller from the Tratamento's tab?

Comment: I solved the problem, but, not as i want to do.
I just added on TableViewController, a method, overriding "viewWillAppear", not calling the super one.

Comment: I Will edit and add the cod of Tratamento's Tab